My discord bot doesnt disconnects from voice channel
I am making a discord bot using .py, I have a lot of "on_message" stuff and I made them work, from different files and stuff, the problem right now is that I am now working with "on_voice_state_update", which detects if a user joined/left a voice channel(as far as I am concerned)
Right now I have this code:
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if after.channel and before.channel is None:
        if not client.voice_clients:
            await after.channel.connect()

It works, and what it does is that when I join a voice channel, my bot also joins that same voice channel(it it has not joined before),
I have this problem that I don't know how to make it leave the voice channel when that channel is empty of users (of course not taking in mind the bot)
I've make it work using commands:
intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.messages = True
intents.voice_states = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', intents = intents)

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def join(ctx):
    if (ctx.author.voice):
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        await channel.connect()
    else:
        await ctx.send("Try joining a voice channel yourself first!")

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def leave(ctx):
    if (ctx.author.voice):
        await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
        await ctx.send("I have left the voice channel!")
    else:
        await ctx.send("I'm not in a voice channel!")

This is so that when I say the command "!join", it joins the voice channel, and "!leave" it leaves the voice channel, but I don't know how to make it automatically that when a channel is (member)empty, the bot leaves also
I've tried this, but it doesn't seems to work
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if after.channel and before.channel is None:
        if not client.voice_clients:
            await after.channel.connect()
    elif before.channel and after.channel is None:
        if member == client.user and len(before.channel.members) == 1:
            await before.channel.disconnect()


Your solution seems to be alright except that you are checking if the member is the client.user aka the bot itself which in this case is wrong since the bot is waiting for the member/s to leave the voice channel while the bot itself stays there until everyone leaves:
elif before.channel and after.channel is None:
     if len(before.channel.members) == 1:
            await before.channel.disconnect()

